# Avoiding if-conditions: Grocery calculator for 3 people

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a simple program for my commune.
We are 3 people and do grocery shopping every week.
At the end of the week we come together and do some accounting so everyone spends the same amount of money.

What i want is a program which outputs something like this:

"Person A owes x money to Person B

Person A owes x money to Person C"

It's no problem for me to calculate if someone needs to give or if someone gets money.
I do it this way (translated in js pseudocode):

```
var a // ammount of money person a spend this week
var b // same for pers b
var c // you guess it

var fa // the factor person a was involved in eating the food (dont ask why)
var fb // this will be range 0 - 1 
var fc // and these 3 need to add up to 1

var sum = a + b + c

var x = sum / 3

//the ammount each person should have paid
var sa = x * fa
var sb = x * fb
var sc = x * fc

/*the resulting numbers tell if a person still needs to pay some money
or gets money and how much (negative or positive)*/
var ra = a - sa
var rb = b - sb
var rc = c - sc
```

Is there any way to get from this result to the output I described earlier without covering all cases (like person a paid less, person b too much, person c too much etc.) with if conditions?

Comment: So do you want to avoid all conditionals like switches and ternary operators as well? Or just a more succinct way of writing the conditionals instead of large branching if's?

Comment: i am searching for a succinct way for a fast solution (i think i would find something, but then i still have 9 cases to cover). i am also interested in avoiding conditions as far as possible. i feel like there is a more elegant way but i cant wrap my head around it right now. there might as well be no other way

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out who owes whom how much, why not pool the amount each person underspent and then reimburse the people who overspent?

Comment: My take. Calculate difference for each person of calculated amount and spent amount (sx-x for each person x). Sort in descending order. For each person, starting with the one owing the most, give to last person what he needs, continue until debt have been paid for first person. Continue until list is done (you need to track paying and payee index). This solution should lead to smallest amount of transactions and builds on the one owing the most paying the one that is owed the most. It automatically deals with the edge case of no debt between you.

Comment: @JLRishe thats good. i still have to make one condition when its the other way around (two people overspent and one underspent). for the sake of simplicity i will do it this way for now. but that still doesnt really answer my question

Comment: @LoveTätting that's great! i try this one. thank you!

Comment: It will take care of two people overspending. The last person will still be given money as he was not paid full by the first. Only move the indices when the person have paid or been paid in full.

Comment: @MaximilianHf There is no "other way around" in what I described above. Each person either owes a certain amount or is owed a certain amount. You've already calculated that in your ra, rb, and rc. In the situation where one person underspent, they would pay up the amount they owed, and the two who overspent would take what was due to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to divide the group between underspenders and overspenders.

For each pair of one underspender and one overspender, the amount owed between them is the underspender's underspent amount, or the overspender's overspent amount, whichever is smaller (the underspender cannot owe more than the amount they underspent, and the overspender should not receive more than the amount they overspent).

Bear in mind this doesn't work for more than 3 people. Any more than 3 and you've just got to pool up the debts and divvy them out.

In the three person case, there are four possible situations:

- All paid the right amount - nobody owes anybody anything
- One paid the right amount - all of the debt is between the other two. The amount the one underspender underspent is equal to the amount the one overspender overspent.
- One overpaid - Their overspend is the sum of the two others' underspend. So each of the others owe the one overspender the amount they underspent (which is smaller than the amount the one person overspent).
- One underpaid - Their underspend is the sum of the two others' overspend. The underspender owes each of the overspenders the amount they overspent (which is smaller than the maount the one person overspent).

The strategy in my second paragraph covers all of the underspend/overspend relationships (take the smaller amount between each pair of people). And if you like, you can have a check for people who neither underspent nor overspent (which I have included below).

```js
function calcDebts(differentials) {
    const underspenders = differentials.filter(d => d.amount < 0);
    const overspenders = differentials.filter(d => d.amount > 0);
    const rightonspenders = differentials.filter(d => d.amount === 0);

    for (let ros of rightonspenders) {
        console.log(`${ros.name} owes nothing`);
    }

    for (let us of underspenders) {
        for (let os of overspenders) {
            console.log(`${us.name} owes ${os.name} ${Math.min(-us.amount, os.amount)}`);
        }
    }
}

console.log('one person underspent');
calcDebts([
    { name: 'a', amount: -3.25 },
    { name: 'b', amount: 1.5 },
    { name: 'c', amount: 1.75 }
]);

console.log('one person overspent');
calcDebts([
    { name: 'a', amount: 2.25 },
    { name: 'b', amount: -1.5 },
    { name: 'c', amount: -0.75 }
]);

console.log('one person paid exactly the right amount');
calcDebts([
    { name: 'a', amount: 1.25 },
    { name: 'b', amount: 0 },
    { name: 'c', amount: -1.25 }
]);

console.log('all paid the right amount');
calcDebts([
    { name: 'a', amount: 0 },
    { name: 'b', amount: 0 },
    { name: 'c', amount: 0 }
]);
```